# How to cast GLKMatrix4 to GLfloat* array?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I have a `GLKMatrix4` variable, and want to use it's `GLfloat *array` values for `glUniformMatrix4fv` function. I googled but not found any useful information. There's a function called `CC3Matrix4x4PopulateFromGLKMatrix4` in cocos3d SDK, but it replys too many files. I really don't want to use it.

Is there any easy way to cast `GLKMatrix4` to `GLfloat* array`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `GLKMatrix4` class has a member `m`, which is exactly the array you need.

```
GLKMatrix4 myMatrix = GLKMatrix4Identity;
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniform, 1, 0, myMatrix.m);
```

Comment: It doesn't work on Swift 2.x. I wrote the solution as below :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to write extension like below.

```
import GLKit

extension GLKMatrix2 {
    var array: [Float] {
        return (0..<4).map { i in
            self[i]
        }
    }
}


extension GLKMatrix3 {
    var array: [Float] {
        return (0..<9).map { i in
            self[i]
        }
    }
}

extension GLKMatrix4 {
    var array: [Float] {
        return (0..<16).map { i in
            self[i]
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can use glUniformMatrix4fv or glUniformMatrix3fv like below

```
...
var modelViewMatrix : GLKMatrix4 = GLKMatrix4Identity
...

glUniformMatrix4fv(self.modelViewMatrixUniform, 1, GLboolean(GL_FALSE), self.modelViewMatrix.array)
```